# How do I create an AHK that disables a specific bluetooth device?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, autohotkey, playback

How do I create an AHK script that automates the following process:

1.Right click audio icon and enters "Playback devices" menu

2.Right click a specific bluetooth device

3.Disables this bluetooth device

4.Saves the settings (Click OK)

I'd of course like to do this without using automated keystrokes/clicks at specific locations. I'm trying not to use any third-party apps if possible.

I've been able to find the following script

```
#Persistent     
#SingleInstance 

#a::
    toggle:=!toggle 
    if toggle
    {
        Run nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Speakers"
        soundToggleBox("Speakers")
    }
    else
    {
        Run nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones"
        soundToggleBox("Headphones")
    }
Return
```

which uses another 3rd party program called "nircmd." I guess I'm trying to gain some insight on how nircmd handles this kind of function, because I would rather not download it.

I'm thinking I could invoke powershell and enter the appropriate commands.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).